# How to handle different types for input of algorithm?

Tags: design-patterns, f#, functional-programming, discriminated-union

I have an algorithm that looks up data based on what the user inputs. There are multiple ways to specify a *unique* record so I am allowing the user to input several different unique identifiers. When I begin writing the algorithm however, alarm bells go on in my head because it seems verbose or non-functional. It just feels like I'm doing something wrong. Let me show you in code.

```
// Types for the domain model
type EmployeeID = ID of int

type EmployeeName =
    { First  : string
      Last   : string }

// Some instances of EmployeeName to use later
let james = {First = "James"; Last = "Winklenaught"}
let ted = {First = "Theodore"; Last = "Chesterton"}

// Input for the algorithm
type matcherInput =
    | EmployeeIDWrapper of EmployeeID
    | EmployeeNameWrapper of EmployeeName

// Output of the algorithm
type matcherOutput = 
    { Info : string }

// Returns data if it found it from our search algorithm
let LookupEmployee (input : matcherInput) : matcherOutput option = 
    (* 
       There's a lot of algorithm here in the real version
       that creates the lookup tables (maps). I just put in
       some dummy data instead. 
    *)
    let numberLookup = 
        Map.ofList [(james, ID 1); (ted, ID 2)]

    let infoLookup = 
        Map.ofList [(ID 1,{Info = "CEO"});(ID 2,{Info = "CFO"})]

    // output
    match input with
    | EmployeeIDWrapper number -> 
        Map.tryFind number infoLookup
    | EmployeeNameWrapper name -> 
        Map.tryFind name numberLookup 
        |> Option.bind (fun number -> Map.tryFind number infoLookup)



// doesn't work = (
LookupEmployee james
LookupEmployee (ID 1)

// right, but verbose
LookupEmployee (EmployeeNameWrapper james)
LookupEmployee (EmployeeIDWrapper (ID 1))
```

Somehow the needing to unwrap everything seems excessive to me. Should I not be using the discriminated union in this case? Is there an established functional design pattern I could leverage?

Comment: Why do you need the `Wrappers`?

Comment: Pure functions can only have one function signature (i.e. one type per parameter). Since I have two types of unique identifiers, I wrap them both in a discriminated union so that I then have one type to feed into the `LookupEmployee` function.

Comment: I mean why can't matcherfunction just be EmployeeID and EmployeeName. Instead of adding an additional layer of a wrapper. something like this: `type matcherInput = EmployeeID | EmployeeName`.

Comment: As written, that does not work. It treats that as a new type and expects 0 arguments when you use it. Why that is, I don't know. I imagine something would break.

Comment: Part of the confusin is coming from trying to use employeeid both as an input and output, the other part is that the record should be wrapped in name. I'll put in a simple fix, but maybe the whole structure should be rethought.

Comment: Agreed. I don't think the structure is right. Do you have an idea of how to improve it? Also, I'm not using `EmployeeID` as output, am I?

Comment: see the edit and comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can of course wrap the same DU case, but then you'd need to call MatcherInput.EmployeeID 2 to get MatcherOutput.EmployeeID. You can hide the magic with some Active Patterns if necessary. The other thing is that the record should be wrapped in Name, I assume.

```
type EmployeeName =
    { First  : string
      Last   : string }

type MatcherInput =
    | Name of EmployeeName
    | EmployeeID of int
    | Info of string

let james = Name {First = "James"; Last = "Winklenaught"}
let ted = Name {First = "Theodore"; Last = "Chesterton"}

let LookupEmployee (input: MatcherInput)  =

    let numberLookup = 
            Map.ofList [(james, EmployeeID 1); (ted, EmployeeID 2)]

    let infoLookup = 
        Map.ofList [(EmployeeID 1,Info "CEO");(EmployeeID 2,Info "CFO")]

    match input with 
    | Name n -> numberLookup.[Name n]
    | EmployeeID _  -> infoLookup.[input]
    | Info _ -> failwith "Dont match on Info"

LookupEmployee ted
LookupEmployee (EmployeeID 2)
```

And in case you are looking to keep the input and output types separate, and will do matching on more types you could you use a generic DU:

```
type EmployeeName =
    { First  : string
      Last   : string }

type MatcherInput =
    | Name of EmployeeName
    | EmployeeID of int

type MatcherOutput<'a> = 
    | Other of 'a
    | Info of string

let james = Name {First = "James"; Last = "Winklenaught"}
let ted = Name {First = "Theodore"; Last = "Chesterton"}

let LookupEmployee (input: MatcherInput) =

    let numberLookup = 
            Map.ofList [(james, EmployeeID 1); (ted, EmployeeID 2)]

    let infoLookup = 
        Map.ofList [(EmployeeID 1,Info "CEO");(EmployeeID 2,Info "CFO")]

    match input with 
    | Name _ -> Other (numberLookup.[input])
    | EmployeeID _ ->  infoLookup.[input]

let x = EmployeeID 1

LookupEmployee ted
LookupEmployee x
```

For another solution I would keep the employee information in one record. And always return the Value as the full record, then extract the necessary info. For the Key you can build various maps for the different parts of the record. you can even nest maps if that's better.